# working with advavced json data anjular js

Tags: json, angularjs

i am new to anjular js , i know how to work with basic json data with anjular js.
i have nauseated json  data

```
[
    {
        "activity_user": "asd@gmail.com",
        "home_id": "1",
        "recent_connect_address": "South Hill Road, Callington, Cornwall ",
        "recent_connect_postcode": "WA3 1PQ",
        "propertyimg": "a.jpg",
        "datemovein": "2014-12-04 00:00:00",
        "datemoveout": "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
        "list": "[{ comment:\"The $190 Bonavita 1900TS made better coffee than the other machines, according to our 10-person tasting panel. \", date:\"2014-12-01 00:00:00\"},{ comment:\"The $190 Bonavita 1900TS made better coffee than the other machines, according to our 10-person tasting panel. \", date:\"2014-12-01 00:00:00\"}]"
    },
    {
        "activity_user": "asd525@gmail.com",
        "home_id": "2",
        "recent_connect_address": "548 Newton Road, Lowton, Warrington ",
        "recent_connect_postcode": "PL17 7LH",
        "propertyimg": "a.jpg",
        "datemovein": "2014-12-01 00:00:00",
        "datemoveout": "2014-12-31 00:00:00",
        "list": "[{ comment:\"We considered 80 Champagne glasses before testing 10 glasses for 12 hours, and we found that the Schott Zwiesel 1872 Enoteca is best for most people. It’s taller, lighter, and thinner than any glass we tried, with tiny etching to keep Champagne carbonated longer. The tulip shape allows more aromas to reach your nose while still maintaining an elegant profile.\", date:\"2014-12-31 00:00:00\"}]"
    }
]
```

now i want to print it out following format

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="property in timeline" >
<div>{{property.activity_user}}</div>
<div class="comments">
<div>{{property.list.}}</div>
</div>

</div>
```

here is my controller but it not work

```
   function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {

            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'my.json'}).success(function(data) {
            $scope.timeline = data;

        });

    };
```

i  refer [Accesing nested JSON with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824959/accesing-nested-json-with-angularjs) but i didn't understand it

Comment: Have you put a break point and stepped through your code yet? You can do this on almost any modern browser using developer tools

Comment: i put console.log(data); it log all array but i doesn't know how to handle it

Comment: Firstly, check the netwrok traffic and make sure that the right data is coming back. then put a breakpoint on $scope.timeline = data (by clicking in the left hand gutter of the script)

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside of the controller, check if the controller is getting hit and the state of the variables, also put one in the callback function, should be able to get a better picture

Comment: Why is your list a string and not an array of comment objects?

Comment: can you explain list a string and not an array of comment objects what you mention

Comment: Normally you would set list to an array like this : "list": [{ comment: "The $190 Bonavita 1900TS made better coffee than the other machines, according to our 10-person tasting panel.", date: "2014-12-01 00:00:00"},{ comment: "The $190 Bonavita 1900TS made better coffee than the other machines, according to our 10-person tasting panel.", date: "2014-12-01 00:00:00"}]

Comment: ok i correct it my in my model but how i print it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in your code right now:

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/buxUpMNfutCgL3Wnko7O?p=preview)**

1. The interpolated value inside your `ng-repeat` for the `property.list` has a dot in it:

change

```
<div>{{property.list.}}</div>
```

to

```
<div>{{property.list}}</div>
```

2. You are missing a `div` element in your html for closing the top level div.
3. You are declaring your controllers in a global manner, this is already deprecated and no longer recommended as of AngularJS 1.3. **[See documentation Arguments Section](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#usage)**.

Instead of declaring it like this:

```
function ListCtrl() {}
```

You can do this instead:

```
angular.module('yourApp', [])

  .controller('ListCtrl', function() {});
```

4. The `list` property is a string, not an array of objects representing comments.

I suggest you change its structure to something like this:

```
"list": [
  { 
    "comment": "The $190 Bonavita 1900TS made better coffee than the other machines, according to our 10-person tasting panel. ", 
    "date":"2014-12-01 00:00:00"
  },
  { 
    "comment": "The $190 Bonavita 1900TS made better coffee than the other machines, according to our 10-person tasting panel. ", 
    "date":"2014-12-01 00:00:00"
  }]
```

---

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('demo', [])

  .controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'my.json'}).success(function(data) {
        $scope.timeline = data;
    });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="property in timeline">
    <div>{{property.activity_user}}</div>
    <div class="comments">
      <div ng-repeat="item in property.list">
        <div>{{item.comment}}</div>
        <em>-- {{item.date}}</em>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**my.json**

```
[
    {
        "activity_user": "asd@gmail.com",
        "home_id": "1",
        "recent_connect_address": "South Hill Road, Callington, Cornwall ",
        "recent_connect_postcode": "WA3 1PQ",
        "propertyimg": "a.jpg",
        "datemovein": "2014-12-04 00:00:00",
        "datemoveout": "2016-12-29 00:00:00",
        "list": [
          { 
            "comment": "The $190 Bonavita 1900TS made better coffee than the other machines, according to our 10-person tasting panel. ", 
            "date":"2014-12-01 00:00:00"
          },
          { 
            "comment": "The $190 Bonavita 1900TS made better coffee than the other machines, according to our 10-person tasting panel. ", 
            "date":"2014-12-01 00:00:00"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        "activity_user": "asd525@gmail.com",
        "home_id": "2",
        "recent_connect_address": "548 Newton Road, Lowton, Warrington ",
        "recent_connect_postcode": "PL17 7LH",
        "propertyimg": "a.jpg",
        "datemovein": "2014-12-01 00:00:00",
        "datemoveout": "2014-12-31 00:00:00",
        "list": [
          { 
            "comment": "We considered 80 Champagne glasses before testing 10 glasses for 12 hours, and we found that the Schott Zwiesel 1872 Enoteca is best for most people. It’s taller, lighter, and thinner than any glass we tried, with tiny etching to keep Champagne carbonated longer. The tulip shape allows more aromas to reach your nose while still maintaining an elegant profile",
            "date":"2014-12-31 00:00:0"
          }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: let me movement to try it

Comment: tanks for all help me

Answer (score 0):

If you re using ( $scope.timeline ),  that means you must use in **html** :

```
{{timeline[0].activity_user}} // print: asd@gmail.com
```

Comment: do you mean you want "Object(property.list).comment"

Comment: yes list comments for each activity_user  "list": "{ comment:'coment1'}  i want to print comment1

Comment: is only give first  element how i go loop trough

Comment: The timeline[0] is spurious. Stay with your property.

Comment: Also I'm mixing my languages. you have to convert your list string to an object before extracting the comment field. I suggest either eval() or JSON.parse()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67828/discussion-between-srinath-and-user2748835).