# Use AngularJS to access nested JSON

Tags: angularjs, json

I have an issue with accessing nested JSON value's. I get the other value's, it's just the nested one's, that I have a problem with. I tried to follow this example but could not get it to work. [Accesing nested JSON with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824959/accesing-nested-json-with-angularjs)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
{{ x.Body + ', ' + x.title + ', ' + x.test_l.filename + ', ' +  x.test_h.filename }}
</li>
</ul>
<!--problem here -->
<ul ng-repeat="x in myData" ng-show="isVisible(x.title)">
  <li ng-repeat="y in x.image">{{y.filename}}</li>
</ul>
```

My problem is the last part. I am trying to get all the filename's of the image.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $http.get("http://localhost:8012/Adrupal/apistuff/test.json").then(function(response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;
  });
});
```

JSON

```
[
  {
"Body": "This is the first test",
"nid": "1",
"test_h": {
  "fid": "33",
  "uid": "1",
  "filename": "h_pic.png",
  "uri": "public://h_pic.png",
  "filemime": "image/png",
  "filesize": "387",
  "status": "1",
  "timestamp": "1465557583",
  "rdf_mapping": [],
  "alt": "",
  "title": "",
  "width": "88",
  "height": "105"
},
"test_l": {
  "fid": "34",
  "uid": "1",
  "filename": "l_pic.png",
  "uri": "public://l_pic.png",
  "filemime": "image/png",
  "filesize": "315",
  "status": "1",
  "timestamp": "1465557850",
  "rdf_mapping": [],
  "alt": "",
  "title": "",
  "width": "67",
  "height": "93"
},
"image": [
  {
    "fid": "28",
    "uid": "1",
    "filename": "image1.png",
    "uri": "public://image1_0.png",
    "filemime": "image/png",
    "filesize": "39965",
    "status": "1",
    "timestamp": "1465556955",
    "rdf_mapping": [],
    "alt": "",
    "title": "",
    "width": "226",
    "height": "208"
  },
  {
    "fid": "35",
    "uid": "1",
    "filename": "image2.png",
    "uri": "public://image2.png",
    "filemime": "image/png",
    "filesize": "64329",
    "status": "1",
    "timestamp": "1465563195",
    "rdf_mapping": [],
    "alt": "",
    "title": "",
    "width": "321",
    "height": "201"
  }
],
"title": "Test 1",
"Check High": "1",
"Check Low": "1"
 }
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at Unerscore.js? They have a `.pick` method that makes this very easy. http://underscorejs.org/#pick      You could also try the `.findKey` method they provide http://underscorejs.org/#findKey

Comment: I have not. Thanks for the advice, i will take a look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with `ng-show="isVisible(x.title)"`. use `ng-show="x.title"` instead of `ng-show="isVisible(x.title)"`.

Fiddle demo : https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/25488/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy, in your case you just have to get the first element of the array (where the object is nested).

`$scope.myData = response.data[0];`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. If anyone else have the same issue here is my solution.

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in myData">
 <li ng-repeat="y in x.image">{{y.filename}}</li>
</ul>
```