# AngularJS: Unable to Send $Http JSON Response to View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-http

Trying to get JSON data from an API and show the result in a view using AngularJS. I'm able to get the data correctly but unable to show it in the view.
When i try to access the object's data the result is always undefined.

Here's what i'm doing...

API Service:

```
myApp.service('apiService', ['$http', function($http)
{
    var api = "http://domain.xpto/api/";

    var self = this;
    this.result;

    var apiService =
    {
        getSection: function(id)
        {
            var url = api + "section/" + id;

            return $http.get(url);
        }
    }

    return apiService;
}]);
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'apiService', function($scope, $routeParams, apiService)
{
    apiService.getSection(1).then(function(response)
    {
        $scope.$applyAsync(function ()
        {
            var data = response.data; //json data as expected
            var section = data.section; //undefined?!
            var images = data.images; //undefined!?

            $scope.title = section.title; //undefined!?         
        });
    });

}]);
```

JSON Result:
[image]

UPDATE: Simplified my apiService based on @Salih's and @elclanrs's suggestion.

Why am i unable to access the inner objects of the json (f.e, data.section.title)?

**UPDATE #2: I'm finally able to access the data. It seems i needed an extra data level to get access to the section object of my json array (response.data.data.section). Honesty i don't understand why. I've accessed the API using jquery and it was strait forward...**

Comment: That first piece of code seems very redundant. Looks like you can replace it with `getSection: function(id) { return $http.get(api + "section/" + id); }`

Comment: Indeed. Updated my api service but my issue still remains. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.parse on response.data to see if it's text?

Comment: @nixkuroi i get a SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse when i try to parse response.data. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I made this plunker to help you!
http://embed.plnkr.co/Yiz9TvVR4Wcf3dLKz0H9/

If I were you, I would use the service function to update the own service value. You already created `this.result`, you can just update its value.

Your Service:

```
myApp.service('apiService', ['$http', function($http)
{
    var api = "http://domain.xpto/api/";

    var self = this;
    this.result = {};

    this.getSection = function(id){
        var url = api + "section/" + id;

        $http.get(url).then(function(res){
            self.result = res;
        });
    }
}]);
```

I wouldn't use a Promise for this case. You can access the Service's var into your Controller and View.

Your controller:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'apiService', 
function($scope, $routeParams, apiService)
{
    $scope.apiSer = apiService;

    $scope.apiSer.getSection(1);

}]);
```

In your View:

```
<pre>{{ apiSer.result }}</pre>
```

And now you'll see your parameter get updated in real time.

Comment: Changed my code based on your suggestion, but i'm still not able to access the inner data values (data.section).

Comment: When i try your solution i get the following error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.xpto/api/section/1/. Redirect from 'http://domain.xpto/api/section/1/' to 'http://domain.xpto/api/section/1' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost.site' is therefore not allowed access.
angular.js:14516 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://domains.xpto/api/secti ...

Comment: You can split your problem into two other problems. The first one is about to parse an JSON from an API (that I showed to you). The second one is about CORS. Try to use the Reddit API first (that I used in Plunker) and use this as example. After that you try to use this other API.

Comment: Solved it! i was using a wrong api address. Nonetheless, i managed to solve my issue. I've updated my question. Thx for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Nope! It was a pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

In your getSection function just write and return the following

return $http.get(url);

Comment: Updated my service and i still can't access the data. What might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use `angular.forEach` method to parse your inner values of the JSON . Take a look at this example [Accesing nested JSON with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824959/accesing-nested-json-with-angularjs)